# Find the result of a function being fed in to a return

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

If stepping through using a debugger and I have a block of code like the following

```
return int Foo()
{
    return Bar();
}
```

Is there any way in the debugger to find out the result of `Bar` before `Foo` returns with the result?

Comment: Did not see that one, it wont let me delete the question now, so I had to vote to close my own question as duplicate.

Comment: [There's some feedback here](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2206747-function-return-value-in-debugger) strongly suggesting that the feature you're looking for didn't make it into 2012 either, which unfortunately leaves you with workarounds.

Comment: It looks like this feature is [here in VS2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/27/seeing-function-return-values-in-the-debugger-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If `Bar()` has no side effects, just evaluate (run) it in a quick watch window.

Otherwise, if it does have side effects, if you can rewrite the code, write it as

```
return int Foo()
{
    var bar = Bar();
    return bar;
}
```

and put a break point on the return.

Comment: And if `Bar()` has side effects, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

would consider using `Command Window`? This can be found on

```
View => Other Windows => Command Window
```

and type

```
? Bar()
```

you will be able to see the result of `Bar()` without even stepping `Foo()`

- [Basics of using the Command Window](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/seealso/archive/2011/01/25/using-the-command-window-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could call Bar() and store the result in a variable and then simply output it. Otherwise you could add a breakpoint and use visual studio's step over functionality to go through the code and variable values line by line.

Comment: I know how to solve it with saving it first, and that is what I normally do to correct the code like that. However I don't understand, using step over it goes from `Bar()` not being executed to returned from Foo in one step.